# content appended with jquery is not part of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an empty div `<div id="content"></div>` to which I add content via jquery append.

```
$('#content').append('<div class="sub">sub1</div>');
$('#content').append('<div class="sub">sub2</div>');
$('#content').append('<div class="sub">sub3</div>');
```

When I click a button I want to run a jquery that reads the content of each sub, but I get nothing, I think because the div elements were added via javascript, so they're not really on the page.

```
$('.sub').each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
}
```

How can I still operate on html added via javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `$('.sub')` not `$('sub')` for  classes.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I think it has to do with the live() issue.

Comment: @sameold You also forgot the ending parenthesis.  The last line needs to be `});`.  See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/u8xhJ/